# Circle equation in homogeneous coordinates

Tags: circles, projective-geometry, homogeneous-equation

Can someone give me a derivation why the circle equation is expressed in homogeneous coordinates like this (as described in [Hartley](https://books.google.de/books?id=e30hAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=circle+equation+homogeneous+hartley&source=bl&ots=jiLB3fc5TX&sig=q2ArpXau7-_qT6fPkw50srcgZUU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihstjqtcjKAhVlmHIKHcBJAD4Q6AEIDzAB#v=onepage&q=circle%20equation%20homogeneous%20hartley&f=false)):

$$
(x-a\cdot w)^2 + (y-b\cdot w)^2 = r^2\cdot w^2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cartesian equation of the circle of radius $r$ and center $(a, b)$ in the $(x, y)$-plane  is
$$
(x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} = r^{2}.
\tag{1}
$$
To "homogenize" in projective coordinates $(w, x, y)$, multiply out, then multiply each monomial by the appropriate power of $w$ to make each term have the same total degree in $(w, x, y)$.

Here, (1) becomes
$$
x^{2} - 2ax + a^{2} + y^{2} - 2by + b^{2} = r^{2},
$$
whose terms have degree at most two in $(x, y)$, so homogenizing gives
$$
x^{2} - 2awx + a^{2}w^{2} + y^{2} - 2bwy + b^{2}w^{2} = r^{2}w^{2},
$$
or
$$
(x - aw)^{2} + (y - bw)^{2} = r^{2}w^{2}.
$$

Comment: Why is this being done? how does it help to have homogeneity in projective coordinates?

Comment: @metsburg: "Why" has (at least) two meanings here, 1. How does the formalism of homogeneous coordinates work in practice?, and 2. How, conceptually, are homogeneous and affine coordinates related? I understood the OP to be asking 1. It sounds as if you're asking 2., which is a lengthier matter. Briefly, homogeneous coordinates are not coordinates in the ordinary sense; only their _ratios_ are well-defined numerical coordinates. Equation (1) doesn't even make sense in homogeneous coordinates; it only makes sense if $x$ and $y$ denote ratios of homogeneous coordinates.